# How to use awaitMessages in Discord.JS v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I want to wait for a message from user used specific command. I know that the filter is probably wrong, but I have no idea now how can I approach this.

I tried something like this:

```
const msg_filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
message.channel.awaitMessages(msg_filter, {
    max: 1
});
```

But now, how can I get this working? Because I googled for several hours and couldn't find a way to solve this issue. I just want to fetch a message from same user as used the command (And I was only able to fetch message from bot, nothing more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a link to the documentation on `TextChannel#awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

But in a nutshell, `awaitMessages` returns a promise that you have to resolve, like this:

```js
const msg_filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages({ filter: msg_filter, max: 1 });

// Or without async/await
const msg_filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
message.channel.awaitMessages({ filter: msg_filter, max: 1 })
  .then((collected) => {
    // ...
  });
```

and `collected` will be a `Collection` of messages. Since you're only collecting 1 message, you can use `collected.first()` to get the first (and only) message in the collection, and then from there you can get it's `.content`, or `.reply()` to it, or do whatever else you want to do with the message.

Comment: its actually` message.channel.awaitMessages({ msg_filter, max: 1 })`

Comment: yep mb - i'll update it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the official discordjs guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors) for this.

Example:

```
// `m` is a message object that will be passed through the filter function
const filter = m => m.content.includes('discord');
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', m => {
    console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's a message collector, not `awaitMessages`

Answer (score 1):

Your format isn't wrong you just need to change the position of filter!

```
const msg_filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
message.channel.awaitMessages({
    filter: msg_filter,
    max: 1
});
```

and make sure you put
`'DIRECT_MESSAGES'`
on intents function