# awaitMessages from the user on discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a system that makes a user enter a code(like a verification code sent to the dms) before doing the action. I am trying to understand how my code can wait for the code to be entered, and I came across the awaitMessages tag. I am trying to understand how I can use it properly in my code. Here is my code.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const { MessageAttachment, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS", "DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING"], partials: ['CHANNEL',] })
const RichEmbed = require("discord.js");
const prefix = "!";



client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const args = commandBody.split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  if (command === "news") {
    if (message.channel.type == "DM") {
      message.author.send(" ");
    }

  }
  if (command === "help") {
    message.author.send("The help desk is avaliable at this website: https://example.com/");
  }
});

client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const args = commandBody.split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "ping") {
    const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
    message.channel.send(`Pong! This message had a latency of ${timeTaken}ms.`);
  }
  if (command === "delete all messages") {
    const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
    const code = Math.random(1,1000)
    message.channel.send(`Executing command. Verification Required.`);
    message.author.send(`Your code is the number ${code}.`)
    message.channel.send(`Please confirm your code. The code has been sent to your dms. Confirm it in here.`)
    message.channel.awaitMessage(code) {
      message.channel.send('confirmed. Doing the action.')
    }
  }
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Be sure to check out the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) on `awaitMessages` but also check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68982614/7740459.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a response from the user, you can use a collector.
You can create a filter to see if the user sending the code is the same as the one who executed the command and if the code sent is correct

```js
const filter = (msg) => msg.author.id === message.author.id && msg.content === code;
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
  filter,
  time: 60000,
});

collector.on('collect', (collectedMessage) => {
  collector.stop('success');
  message.channel.send('confirmed. Doing the action.')
});

collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
  if (reason === 'success') return;
  else message.channel.send('Timeout or error');
});
```